# Add tooltip on a URL in a datatable not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, tooltip

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation):

> To display the URL value as a tooltip on a URL, pass in the tooltip
> value:

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Company Website', fieldName: 'website', type: 'url',
    typeAttributes: { tooltip: { fieldName: 'website' } } },
    // other column data
]
```

I can't make it work, when I hover over a field, the tooltip appears but not with the text that I set in 'fieldName'.

You can test it [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/7f5ZErMt1emj6cqd93te).

Relevant part of my code:

```
const columns = [{
    label: "Column",
    fieldName: "Hoveroverme",
    sortable: true,
    wrapText: true,
    type: "url",
    typeAttributes: {
        label: {
            fieldName: "Show this text in a tooltip",
        },
        tooltip: {
            fieldName: "Show this text in a tooltip"
        },
        target: "_self",
    },
}, ];
```

Comment: I also want to view Demo component. Its not working right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `{ fieldName: 'someFieldName' }`, it doesn't show the text, instead it shows the dynamic value from the data instead; in other words, it wouldn't show `Show this text in a tooltip`, because you're telling it to show a field value. This causes it to revert back to what a URL shows by default, being the label.

To show a literal value, use a string:

```
{ tooltip: 'Show this text in the tooltip' }
```

To show a field value, use the object notation:

```
{ tooltip: { fieldName: 'id' } }
```

[Here's your demo, modified](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/nEgmcGFDoTEKT15R7sNh).

Comment: the demo component has been removed. Can i check that again